# Reshaping order in PyTorch - Fortran-like index ordering

Tags: numpy, view, pytorch, reshape

In numpy, there is an ordering feature for reshaping arrays, by default it is C, but you can specify other ordering like F:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2))
f = np.reshape(a, (2, 3), order='F') # Fortran-like index ordering
c = np.reshape(a, (2, 3)) 
print('a= \n', a)
print('f= \n', b)
print('c= \n', c)
```

the result:

```
a= 
 [[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]]
f= 
 [[0 4 3]
 [2 1 5]]
c= 
 [[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
```

There is no such option in torch.reshape or tensor.view for reshaping in F order.
Is there any way to do that F order reshape in PyTorch? I need everything to be in PyTorch.

Comment: Reshape the array in NumPy and then convert it to a PyTorch tensor?

Comment: Thanks, but I need everything to be in PyTorch, as I want to use the function as a customized loss function in my DNN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think pytorch has built-in support for this. That said you can achieve the desired result using [`Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute). Unfortunately I doubt this will be very efficient since AFAIK permute internally makes a copy of the tensor.

```py
def reshape_fortran(x, shape):
    if len(x.shape) > 0:
        x = x.permute(*reversed(range(len(x.shape))))
    return x.reshape(*reversed(shape)).permute(*reversed(range(len(shape))))
```

Example usage:

```py
a = torch.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)
f = reshape_fortran(a, (2, 3))
c = a.reshape(2, 3)
```

which results in

```py
a = 
tensor([[0, 1],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 5]])
f =
tensor([[0, 4, 3],
        [2, 1, 5]])
c =
tensor([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]])
```

Comment: Thanks Jodge, that's a very efficient answer. I implemented it by consecutive transpose, flatten and rearranging, which was not efficient though practical. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

[jodag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63964246/15486340) works perfectly fine and I have a further test about the performance. The `permute`-based reshape takes about 10 times computation time compared to the built-in `reshape`. However, in `numpy`, the built-in Fortran like `reshape` also takes 10 times of the computational time. So this method is quite efficient :)

Here's the test code and results from i9-10900X and RTX2080Ti:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch
import time

dim1 = 40
dim2 = 50
dim3 = 5

def reshape_fortran(x, shape):
    if len(x.shape) > 0:
        x = x.permute(*reversed(range(len(x.shape))))
    return x.reshape(*reversed(shape)).permute(*reversed(range(len(shape))))

torch.cuda.set_device(0)
device = torch.device('cuda')

x = [torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(dim1, dim2)).to(device) for _ in range(100)]
xx = [torch.from_numpy(np.random.rand(dim1, dim2)).to(device) for _ in range(100)]
for i in range(100):
    y = x[i].reshape([dim2, dim1])
# c reshape
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    y = xx[i].reshape([dim2, dim3, -1])
t1 = time.time()

# fortran reshape
for i in range(100):
    yy = reshape_fortran(xx[i], [dim2, dim3, -1])
t2 = time.time()

print(f'torch build-in reshape: {(t1 - t0)/100} s')
print(f'torch permute reshape: {(t2 - t1)/100} s')

x = [np.random.rand(dim1, dim2) for _ in range(100)]
xx = [np.random.rand(dim1, dim2) for _ in range(100)]
for i in range(100):
    y = x[i].reshape([dim2, dim3, -1])
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    yy = xx[i].reshape([dim2, dim3, -1])
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    yyy = xx[i].reshape([dim2, dim3, -1], order='F')
t2 = time.time()

print(f'numpy C reshape: {(t1 - t0)/100} s')
print(f'numpy F reshape: {(t2 - t1)/100} s')
```

```
torch build-in reshape: 9.72747802734375e-07 s
torch permute reshape: 1.1897087097167968e-05 s
numpy C reshape: 3.0517578125e-07 s
numpy F reshape: 2.474784851074219e-06 s
```